# Gelfand Kirillov dimension of induced modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

How does the Gelfand-Kirillov dimension of induced modules behave?
In patricular, if $S$ is an Ore extension of $R$, how is the GK-dimension of an $R$-module say $N$ related to the GK dimension of $N \otimes_R S$ ?